# C Map insert iterator bind

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way I can utilize boost::bind to 'bind' the value of a set of keys in doing an iterator insert? Essentially, I want to iterate through a set of keys, and insert them into a map with a given value.

```
map<int, int> mymap;
set<int> myset;
myset.insert(1);
myset.insert(2);
myset.insert(3);
....
myset.insert(100);


for_each(myset.begin(), myset.end(), boost::bind(&mymap.insert,_1, 5); //Should be some make_pair() in here, but not sure how to make this work
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Map all the numbers to 5?

Comment: Yep, exactly.  I know I could iterate through, but was looking for a cleaner one liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you will be not happy with it.

It will look like:

```
    std::for_each(
      myset.begin()
    , myset.end()
    , std::bind(
          &map<int, int>::insert
        , &mymap
        , std::bind(
              std::make_pair<int, int>
              , std::bind(
                    &std::set<int>::iterator::operator*
                  , std::placeholders::_1
                  )
              , 5
            )
        )
    );
```

(didn't tested this code)

Comment: Oh dear.. The one liner approach is much more complicated than I had imagined. Thank you!

Comment: @bamboon you can, but you must cast them to the form you're after.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, but that gets ugly and unreadable. I would use a lambda instead(assuming C++11).